# How to remove whitespace around <lb break="no"/> elements in a XSLT file?

Tags: xslt

Essentially, I'm struggling with the same **XSLT problem** as another questioner asking on this site, namely the user "bigsky" in a post of 2013 (s. [Trim white-spaces at the end of lines only before a specific tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18192715/trim-white-spaces-at-the-end-of-lines-only-before-a-specific-tag)). But in spite of a useful hint (in the answer of Sperberg-McQueen), I couldn't figure out a satisfying solution for the issue.
What I'm trying to do is, transforming an XML file into a readable HTML document, to create a running "body" text and recombine at line breaks the strings of words divided, that is interrupted by an `<lb break="no"/>` element, in my original document - but recombine them **without whitespaces**!
Having played around with several templates in my XSLT stylesheet, I defined one - following the hint of the post mentioned above - to process all nodes preceding a `<lb break="no"/>` element, and I tried to remove their leading and trailing whitespaces making use of the `normalize-space()` function, so that the strings preceding and following the specified `<lb>` nodes should be concatenated in the output.
Now, for the most part of the cases, I've actually got the output I desired - however, in some places appears (to my surprise) **whitespace *before* the re-concatenated string**, which has no counterpart in my XML file and which I would like to get rid of.

As the relevant files deal with a document of a certain length, I'll show you only extracts of the code - but I'll include parts where the transformation works as wanted, as well as parts where the transformation produces unexpected whitespace.
Concerning the text document at issue, just a brief note for your information: The XML file covers the text of a medieval Latin manuscript according to conventions of the Text Encoding Initiative (TEI) and is, among other things, intended to record palaeographic features of the manuscript (- in case you wonder about the tags/elements I've used). Actually, I'd like to ask you to have a look primarily at the sections around the `<lb break="no"/>` elements and ignore the details of my text encoding - but at the same time I wanted to show you the selected passages as they appear in my edition (not least because I'm unsure as to the role of adjacent elements ...).

--> Extract from the **XML file**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-model href="http://www.tei-c.org/release/xml/tei/custom/schema/relaxng/tei_all.rng" type="application/xml" schematypens="http://relaxng.org/ns/structure/1.0"?>
<?xml-model href="http://www.tei-c.org/release/xml/tei/custom/schema/relaxng/tei_all.rng" type="application/xml" schematypens="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron"?>

<TEI xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">

  <teiHeader>
    <fileDesc>
      <titleStmt>
        <title>Gesta Francorum et aliorum Hierosolimitanorum</title>
        <!-- some code -->
      </titleStmt>
      <publicationStmt>
        <publisher></publisher>     
      </publicationStmt>
      <sourceDesc>
        <msDesc xml:lang="en">               
          <msIdentifier>
            <settlement>Vatican City (Rome)</settlement>
            <repository key="https://www.vaticanlibrary.va">Biblioteca Apostolica Vaticana</repository>
            <idno type="shelfmark">Reg. lat. 572</idno>
            <msName>Codex Vaticanus Reginensis latinus 572</msName>
          </msIdentifier>
          <!-- some code -->
        </msDesc>
      </sourceDesc> 
    </fileDesc>

    <!-- some code -->

  </teiHeader>

  <text>
    <body>
      <div type="text" subtype="book" n="1">     
        <ab>
          <!-- FIRST PASSAGE -->
          <pb n="1v"/>
            <!-- some code -->
            <lb n="21"/>... <hi rend="colour:red">A</hi>it 
            <lb n="22"/><expan>na<am><g ref="#macron"/></am><ex>m</ex><am><g ref="#abbr_que"/></am><ex>que</ex></expan> <rs type="person" ref="http://d-nb.info/gnd/118763873"><expan>domn<am><g ref="#abbr_us"/></am><ex>us</ex></expan> <expan>ap<ex>osto</ex>l<am><g ref="#macron"/></am>icus</expan></rs>: <said aloud="true"><hi rend="colour:red">F</hi>ratres, uos

          <pb n="2r"/>
            <lb n="1"/>oportet multa pati <expan><am><g ref="#p_flourish"/></am><ex>pro</ex></expan> nomine <choice><orig><expan><am>xp<g ref="#macron"/></am><ex>christ</ex>i</expan></orig><reg>Christi</reg></choice>, ui
            <lb n="2" break="no"/>delicet miserias, <expan>pau<am><g ref="#p_stroke"/></am><ex>per</ex>tates</expan>, nuditates,
            <lb n="3"/><expan><am><g ref="#p_stroke"/></am><ex>per</ex>secutiones</expan>, egestates, infirmitates,
            <lb n="4"/>fames, sites, <expan><am>&amp;</am><ex>et</ex></expan> alia huiusmodi ... </said>

          <!-- SECOND PASSAGE -->
          <!-- some code -->
          <pb n="3r"/>
            <lb n="13" rend="text-indent -1em"/><hi rend="colour:red">A</hi>nte <expan>porta<am><g ref="#macron"/></am><ex>m</ex></expan> castri erat puteus, <expan><am>&amp;</am><ex>et</ex></expan> ad <expan>pede<am><g ref="#macron"/></am><ex>m</ex></expan>
            <lb n="14"/>castri fons uiuus, iuxta <expan>que<am><g ref="#macron"/></am><ex>m</ex></expan> exiit <persName><expan>Rai
            <lb n="15" break="no"/>nald<am><g ref="#abbr_us"/></am><ex>us</ex></expan></persName> insidiari <orgName type="ethnic"><choice><orig>turcos</orig><reg>Turcos</reg></choice></orgName>. <hi rend="colour:red">V</hi>enientes <expan>u<am><g ref="#o_superscript"/></am><ex>ero</ex></expan>
            <lb n="16"/><orgName type="ethnic"><choice><orig>turci</orig><reg>Turci</reg></choice></orgName> <date when="1096-09-20" type="occasion">in festo sancti <expan>Michahel<ex>is</ex></expan></date>, inuener<ex>un</ex>t
            <lb n="17"/><persName><expan>Rainaldu<am><g ref="#macron"/></am><ex>m</ex></expan></persName> <expan><am>&amp;</am><ex>et</ex></expan> <expan>q<am><g ref="#i_superscript"/></am><ex>ui</ex></expan> <expan>cu<am><g ref="#macron"/></am><ex>m</ex></expan> eo erant, <expan>occider<ex>un</ex>t<am><g ref="#macron"/></am><am><g ref="#abbr_que"/></am><ex>que</ex></expan>
            <lb n="18"/><orgName type="ethnic"><choice><orig>turci</orig><reg>Turci</reg></choice></orgName> multos ex eis. <hi rend="colour:red">A</hi>lii fugerunt in
            <lb n="19"/><expan>castru<am><g ref="#macron"/></am><ex>m</ex></expan>. <hi rend="colour:red">Q</hi>uod <expan>c<am><g ref="#macron"/></am><ex>on</ex>festi<am><g ref="#macron"/></am><ex>m</ex></expan> <orgName type="ethnic"><choice><orig>turci</orig><reg>Turci</reg></choice></orgName> <expan>obseder<ex>un</ex>t<am><g ref="#macron"/></am></expan>,
            <lb n="20"/><expan>eis<am><g ref="#abbr_que"/></am><ex>que</ex></expan> <expan>aqua<am><g ref="#macron"/></am><ex>m</ex></expan> <expan>abstuler<ex>un</ex>t<am><g ref="#macron"/></am></expan>. <hi rend="colour:red">F</hi>ueruntque nostri
            <lb n="21"/>in tanta afflictione sitis, ut fleboto
            <lb n="22" break="no"/>marent suos <expan>eq<am><g ref="#o_superscript"/></am><ex>uo</ex>s</expan> <expan><am>&amp;</am><ex>et</ex></expan> asinos, <expan>quo<am><g ref="#abbr_rum"/></am><ex>rum</ex></expan> <expan>sangui<add place="below">ne<am><g ref="#macron"/></am><ex>m</ex></add></expan>

          <pb n="3v"/>
            <lb n="1"/>bibebant. <hi rend="colour:red">A</hi>lii mittebant zonas <expan>at<am><g ref="#abbr_que"/></am><ex>que</ex></expan>
            <lb n="2"/>panniculos in <expan>piscina<am><g ref="#macron"/></am><ex>m</ex></expan>, <expan><am>&amp;</am><ex>et</ex></expan> inde <expan>exp<am><g ref="#i_superscript"/></am><ex>ri</ex>meba<hi rend="ligature">nt</hi></expan>
            <lb n="3"/><expan>aqua<am><g ref="#macron"/></am><ex>m</ex></expan> in os <expan>suu<am><g ref="#macron"/></am><ex>m</ex></expan>. <hi rend="colour:red">A</hi>lii mingebant <choice><orig>iN</orig><reg>in</reg></choice>
            <lb n="4"/>pugillo alterius, <expan><am>&amp;</am><ex>et</ex></expan> bibebant. <hi rend="colour:red">A</hi>lii fodi
            <lb n="5" break="no"/>ebant <expan>humida<am><g ref="#macron"/></am><ex>m</ex></expan> <expan>t<am><g ref="#macron"/></am><ex>e</ex>r<ex>r</ex>a<am><g ref="#macron"/></am><ex>m</ex></expan> ...
            <!-- some code -->

          <!-- THIRD PASSAGE -->
          <pb n="7v"/>
            <!-- some code -->
            <lb n="9"/>... <hi rend="colour:red">Q</hi>ui <expan>resp<am><g ref="#macron"/></am><ex>on</ex>der<ex>un</ex>t<am><g ref="#macron"/></am></expan>:
            <lb n="10" rend="text-indent -1em"/><said aloud="true"><hi rend="colour:red">N</hi>os <expan>neq<am><g ref="#i_superscript"/></am><ex>ui</ex>m<am><g ref="#abbr_us"/></am><ex>us</ex></expan> aliud agere. <hi rend="colour:red">I</hi>n roga <rs type="person" ref="http://d-nb.info/gnd/118501925"><expan>im<am><g ref="#p_stroke"/></am><ex>per</ex>a
            <lb n="11" break="no"/>toris</expan></rs> locati <expan>sum<am><g ref="#abbr_us"/></am><ex>us</ex></expan>, <expan><am>&amp;</am><ex>et</ex></expan> <expan>q<am><g ref="#i_superscript"/></am><ex>ui</ex>cq<am><g ref="#i_superscript"/></am><ex>ui</ex>d</expan> <expan>nob<am><g ref="#macron"/></am><ex>is</ex></expan> imperat
            <lb n="12"/>nos oportet implere.</said>
            <!-- some code -->

        </ab>
      </div>
    </body>
  </text>
</TEI>
```

--> Extract from the **XSLT file**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-model href="http://www.tei-c.org/release/xml/tei/custom/schema/relaxng/tei_all.rng" type="application/xml" schematypens="http://relaxng.org/ns/structure/1.0"?>
<?xml-model href="http://www.tei-c.org/release/xml/tei/custom/schema/relaxng/tei_all.rng" type="application/xml"
    schematypens="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron"?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xpath-default-namespace="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

  <xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8"/>

  <xsl:template match="TEI/text/body/div/ab">
    <!-- <xsl:value-of select="."/> -->
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- HERE IS THE TEMPLATE DEALING WITH <LB>-NODES (!) -->
  <xsl:template match="text()[following-sibling::*[1][self::lb[@break='no']]]">
    <seg style="color:green"><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()" /></seg>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="TEI/text/body/div/ab/descendant-or-self::hi[@rend='colour:red']">
    <seg style="color:darkred; font-weight:bold"><xsl:value-of select="."/></seg>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="TEI/text/body/div/ab/descendant-or-self::hi[@rend='capitalize colour:red']">
    <seg style="color:darkred; font-weight:bold"><xsl:value-of select="."/></seg>
  </xsl:template> 
  
  <xsl:template match="TEI/text/body/div/ab/descendant-or-self::orig"/>
  <xsl:template match="TEI/text/body/div/ab/descendant-or-self::am"/>

  <!-- MAIN TEMPLATE: HTML output -->
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>
          Gesta Francorum 1 (XSLT / test)
        </title>
        <style>
          @font-face {
          font-family: "Palemonas MUFI";
          src: local("Palemonas MUFI Standard") url("file:///C:/Windows/Fonts/PalemMUFI-reg.ttf") format("truetype");
          }
          /* some code */
        </style>
      </head>

      <body>
        <div id="header">
          <h1>
            <xsl:value-of select="TEI/teiHeader/fileDesc/titleStmt/title"/>
          </h1>
          <!-- some code -->
        </div>
   
        <div id="main_content">
            
          <div id="main_content_text">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="TEI/text/body/div/ab"/>
          </div>
            
        </div>

        <!-- some code -->
                      
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you have a look at the **HTML output**, you will see that there is something going wrong (I was able to reproduce the problem with these extracts):
-- In the FIRST PASSAGE I get *"Christi **, vi**delicet miserias"*, instead of the expected *"Christi, videlicet miserias"* - note the additional whitespace before the first string of the concatenation, that is *not* in the XML file!
-- In the SECOND PASSAGE I get, as desired, *"**Rai**naldus"* and *"**in tanta afflictione sitis, ut fleboto**marent"*, but at the end unfortunately *"A **lii fodiebant**"* instead of *"Alii fodiebant"* - again, with an additional whitespace before the first string of the concatenation.
-- In the THIRD PASSAGE I get *"in roga imper **a**toris"* instead of the expected *"in roga imperatoris"* - for a third time, with an additional whitespace before the first string of the concatenation.

Can somebody tell me if I am overlooking relevant details concerning the `normalize-space()` function or one of the XML tags, or have you got a clue where the unwanted whitespace comes from (- again, in the majority of cases my simple solution seems to work)?
Any help from the XSLT experts out there would be appreciated.

(JTLYK: I use the Oxygen XML Editor 21.1 for creating the XML and XSLT files, my browser is Mozilla Firefox 81.0)

=====================================

**UPDATE:**
Thanks to a suggestion by **Martin Honnen** (s. his answer below), I think I was able to produce a "quick & dirty" solution for the issue. Using a revised `<xsl:output>` declaration (as suggested by Honnen = `<xsl:output method="html" indent="no" encoding="UTF-8" version="5"/>`), the whitespaces that in my output preceded the `<seg>` elements of the `<lb break="no"/>` templates, could easily be removed.
Now, I had the problem in some other places of my document that a concatenated string around a `<lb break="no"/>` element was also linked without dividing whitespace to the preceding element (= due to my `normalize-space()` command). I solved it simply by shifting such whitespace, where needed, into the preceding element.
Just a very short example of my TEI/XML file:
Instead of

```
<lb n="4"/><expan>specialit<am><g ref="macron"/></am><ex>er</ex></expan> in euan
<lb n="5" break="no"/>gelio dicens ...
```

I wrote:

```
<lb n="4"/><expan>specialit<am><g ref="macron"/></am><ex>er</ex> </expan>in euan
<lb n="5" break="no"/>gelio dicens ...
```

**Output**:
Instead of *"specialiterin euangelio dicens"* for the first snippet, now *"specialiter in euangelio dicens"*, as is desired ...

To be honest, I'm still in doubt whether this is "good" encoding style ...
(What about a solution with the XSLT function `ends-with()`, as Sperberg-McQueen had in mind answering the 2013 post? Or perhaps a solution with `concatenate()`? I still have to figure that out ...)

Comment: I'm not clear from reading this whether you're concerned with whitespace in the output HTML file, or whitespace in the page that appears when a browser renders the HTML. Note that the output="html" method essentially allows the XSLT processor to make its own decisions about whitespace in the HTML file provided it doesn't affect the browser rendition of the file.

Comment: @Michael Kay: Thank you for the hint, I hadn't thought about this issue ... Actually, I'm concerned with the HTML as rendered by my browser, where the unwanted whitespaces appear (btw, I forgot to mention in the post that the green colored `<seg>` elements in the `<lb>` template are meant to make visible the passages in the browser output). -- As I have checked in Oxygen's *"results" section*, within the HTML output of the XSLT processor the green colored `<seg>` elements (= representing the first parts of my concatenated strings) appear always in a new line ...

Comment: Sorry that I've overlooked such an essential point ... Seems to indicate that my problem with the `<lb break="no"/>` elements cannot be solved with the `normalize-space()` function, right? (Either the strings at issue will, if wrapped in an HTML tag, be separated from what precedes them per *whitespace*, or they will be concatenated with the text/node preceding and the one following them.)

Comment: Is there a `seg` element in any version of HTML? As for the input, if white space matters, do you perhaps need to use a container element that wraps line structures? I am not very familiar with TEI I am afraid but for sure it looks odd that inside the `ab` element you have that free mixture of text and inline elements.

Comment: Your question is well justified, `<seg>` is, of course, an XML element (here: TEI) - but it shows up as `<seg> ... </seg>` in the HTML code (both in Oxygen and in the "view-source"-page corresponding to the output of my browser) ... I'm well aware of the difference between XML and HTML, having read e.g. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37084310/whats-the-difference-between-seg-and-span), but I'm not sure as to how the `<seg>` elements are actually rendered in my file ... Line-wrapping element: I thought `<lb/>` would do the job? ... Will have a look at your answer a.s.a.p.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try with `<xsl:output method="html" indent="no" encoding="UTF-8" version="5"/>` or perhaps make sure you use a well defined inline element like `span` instead of `seg`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion that actually helped me to create at least a working solution (s. the Update of my post) ... If it is not overly simplistic or "dirty" to your eyes, I would, of course, mark your answer as "accepted"!

Comment: @interrogator, as far as I can tell the superfluous whitespace you complained about in your question are introduced due to the default `indent="yes"` for the method `html` together with the use of an undefined `seg` element which the serializer will serialize as a block element I think, introducing line breaks you then see as whitespace between letters. So changing to `indent="no"` avoids that problem, I would also think that using a defined HTML inline element like `span` instead of `seg` might avoid the problem, even if you use `indent="yes"`.

Comment: Absolutely right, the `<span>` version works for me, with indentation = "yes" ... I was probably absorbed in my TEI work, `<seg>` should actually be reserved for the XML file! --- Thank you again for answering this post!